# How much are large retail LEGO Minifigures worth?

Tags: minifigures, shopping, value

I have an extra large LEGO figure *(approximately 19 inches/48 cm tall)* that I wish to sell.  This is an item which has only been available to retailers as part of merchandising the stores.

Any ideas how much these are worth?

Comment: I think you should restructure your question so that it we can apply the answers to a broader audience, this question seems to me like it will only bring answers that will fit your situation.  you should ask something like "How would you figure out the worth of a Lego Figure?" or "what kind of information is needed to determine the value of a certain set of Legos?"

Comment: pictures would be good too...

Answer (score 5):

These typically go for several hundred USD at the low end, and can be up to several thousand for the rarer display figures.

One way to get an idea of the current market price is to check out the items currently for sale on Bricklink. A search for ['display figure' in the gear category](http://www.bricklink.com/browseList.asp?q=display+figure&itemType=G&catID=) should give you a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have been making a list of these over the past few months.  I have about 43 and I think that another 50 or so exists.  You can see the full list here. http://www.minifigpriceguide.com/MAXIFIGS.0.html

I think that these figures generally go for between 400 - 1500 depending on the character.  The last Spiderman Doc Ock combo that I saw went for around 3000.

Comment: Hi Logan - any chance you could include a currency in your answer - 400-1500USD is fairly different to 400-1500GBP and is very different to 400-1500DKK ;)